# How can Mobile Mouse invoke multi-touch events without using a private API

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

So I was trying to add some features to an app that would work similarly to Mobile Mouse (you can use your iPhone as a touchpad). Anyway I ran into a roadblock with multi-touch gestures, because there is no public API for creating them programmatically.

So my question is, if Mobile Mouse is using a private API, why didn't Apple reject the app? Which leads me to the question of, if they didn't use a private API, how might they have done it?